# The Autodiscover service couldn't be located, when try to access exchange

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

with my webapplication, I like to connect to Microsoft exchange and send an email. Everytime I debug the code, it works till it reaches the line:

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl(Constants.ExchangeInfo.AutodiscoveryURL, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

Then the arrow showing the line, where it debugs disappears and the page never stops loading.

```
public static void SendEmail(string subject, string body, List<string> recipientsList)
        {
            try
            {
                ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
                service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(
                   Constants.ExchangeInfo.ExchangeUserName
                   , Constants.ExchangeInfo.ExchangePassword
                   , Constants.ExchangeInfo.ExchangeDomain);

                service.TraceEnabled = true;
                service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
                service.AutodiscoverUrl(Constants.ExchangeInfo.AutodiscoveryURL, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

                EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.Body = body;

                foreach (string recipient in recipientsList)
                {
                    Log.LogError(Log.Module.Email, recipient, recipient, recipient);
                    message.ToRecipients.Add(recipient);
                }

                // Send the e-mail message and save a copy.
                message.SendAndSaveCopy();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.LogError(Log.Module.Email, "Email", ex.ToString(), "System");
            }
        }

 private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
        {
            // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
            bool result = false;

            Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

            // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
            // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
            // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
            if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I don't know where the problem could be, because the page don't stops loading, but also never go in my catch block.

Would be really nice, if someone could help me!

EDIT:

Just get the exception: {"The Autodiscover service couldn't be located."}
What could be the reason for that?

Comment: try using email address as first paramater to `service.AutodiscoverUrl`

Comment: I already tried using the email address instead of a constant with the email address as value, but it works either

Comment: maybe try using network credentials? 
`service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailAddress, Password);`
try looking at the examples here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c

Comment: I already have an other application with the same code an their it works and I like to have in both codes the same way theirfore

Comment: Try autodiscover by the mail adress instead of the url directly service.AutodiscoverUrl("yourExchangeEmail");

Comment: I tried it, but I got the same error message

Comment: I would get this error even if it wasn't an auto-discovery issue. For me, when I hard coded the username domain and password fields, I found out there was an issue with my parameters being passed in to define network crednetials. I would recommend verifying user account either in OWA or via EWSEditor just to verify authentication and then statically set the string values in your code just to eliminate possible issues there.

Comment: you can also ctrl-right click on the outlook icon in lower right, there is option to test e-mail AutoConfirguration, I used this to validate autodiscovery as well.

Comment: I also defined credentials this way service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(new System.Net.networkCredential(emailAddress, Password, Domain)); I did this because it let me pass in a SecureString as Password

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850890/the-autodiscover-service-couldnt-be-located?rq=1